# How do you find the employee record by id from a Set of Employees without using the for loops or iterator?

Tags: java, loops, collections, set, getter-setter

Example:

```
Employee Record
1, Paul, 100
2, Peter, 200
3, Riana, 100
```

Search by department id - 100 displays

```
1, Paul,100 3, Riana,100
```

Note:

1. Employee records are stored in Set in order to avoid duplicate employee id.
2. Try to use getters and setters only to retrieve the employee record, instead of looping over employees
3. Builder pattern is used to build employee records.

Comment: You've got to iterate it somehow. Streams?

Comment: The notes are unhelpful at best, misleading at worst. There's no way to accomplish this without looping through the employees in the `Set` in some way.

Comment: why set ? use a map better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Streams can be used to apply filter on record sets and fetch results. Below is the sample code where employee details are displayed based on the search criteria on departmentId.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class EmployeeDetails {
int employeeId;
String name;
int departmentId;

public EmployeeDetails(int employeeId, String name, int departmentId) {
    this.employeeId = employeeId;
    this.name = name;
    this.departmentId = departmentId;
}

public int getEmployeeId() {
    return employeeId;
}

public void setEmployeeId(int employeeId) {
    this.employeeId = employeeId;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getDepartmentId() {
    return departmentId;
}

public void setDepartmentId(int departmentId) {
    this.departmentId = departmentId;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "EmployeeDetails{" +
            "employeeId=" + employeeId +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", departmentId=" + departmentId +
            '}';
}
}

public class Employee{
public static void main(String[] args){
    EmployeeDetails employee1 = new EmployeeDetails(1, "Paul", 100);
    EmployeeDetails employee2 = new EmployeeDetails(2, "Peter", 200);
    EmployeeDetails employee3 = new EmployeeDetails(3, "Raina", 100);
    Set<EmployeeDetails> employees = new HashSet<>();

    employees.add(employee1);
    employees.add(employee2);
    employees.add(employee3);

    int filteredDepartmentId = 100;

    employees.stream()
            .filter(e -> Integer.compare(filteredDepartmentId, e.getDepartmentId()) == 0)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
}
```